# Ubuntu 15.10 wait on all "auto" if cable unplugged

Tags: boot, networking, drivers, server, 15.10

I have freshly installed ubuntu server 15.10 on my dell inspirion 1545 with kde desktop and sddm desktop manager. I have installed the proper wireless drivers (b43-fwcutter) which work since i'm using the wireless connection to ask this question right now. I have set up my network interfaces as dhcp interfaces, and both seem to work. I'll post the config (/etc/network/interfaces) below:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto enp9s0
iface enp9s0 inet dhcp

auto wlp12s0
iface wlp12s0 inet dhcp
```

Here are the results to `ifconfig`:

```
enp9s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:23:ae:3c:71:34  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
      Interrupt:18 

enp9s0:avahi Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:23:ae:3c:71:34  
      inet addr:169.254.5.252  Bcast:169.254.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      Interrupt:18 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:2546 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:2546 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:276769 (276.7 KB)  TX bytes:276769 (276.7 KB)

wlp12s0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:22:5f:aa:6b:71  
      inet addr:192.168.178.14  Bcast:192.168.178.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::222:5fff:feaa:6b71/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:7803 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:207
      TX packets:7230 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:5059140 (5.0 MB)  TX bytes:927930 (927.9 KB)
      Interrupt:17 Base address:0xc000
```

For some reason however, my laptop chooses to wait for 2 minutes and 10 seconds at boot to `wait for all "auto" /etc/network/interfaces` when i don't have an internet cable plugged into my network card. It doesn't do this when the cable is plugged in. Is there another way to configure my network interfaces to avoid the waiting time at boot? If not, in ubuntu 14.10 and lower i could bypass the waiting for interfaces by editing the `failsafe.conf` file. Is there a way to bypass the waiting time for ubuntu 15.10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a temporary fix i commented out the following lines:

```
#auto enp9s0
#iface enp9s0 inet dhcp
```

It removes the message from boot and makes my laptop start up without the waiting, however i feel like it's not a clean solution because every time i want to switch between internet connections (cable/wifi) i have to alter the `/etc/network/interfaces` file. If anybody ever finds a good solution to this problem i'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `allow-hotplug` instead of `auto` on the interface, so you would have

> allow-hotplug enp9s0
>
> iface enp9s0 inet dhcp

which would not delay the startup process if there is no cable connected